# laravel - update the model(!) without selecting first

Tags: laravel, model

I have the following `ResearchModel` (eloquent):

```
$research = new ResearchModel();
$research->id = 2;
$research->name = "test";
$research->save();
```

I am expecting Laravel to run an `update` statement (because I set the `id`), but it runs an insert statement instead.

`$research->update();` wont do anything.

I don't want to use `array` in this case because I need the eloquent model events to be triggered.

I also don't want to run `ResearchModel::find(2);` before, this will cause significant performance problems in my use-case.

Is there any way to tell Laravel to update by the `id`?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dirty solution:

```
// Create an instance without insert to database.
$instance = new ResearchModel;
$instance->id = 2;
$instance->name = "test";

// Set the instance status directly.
$instance->exists = true;

// Update database without model.
ResearchModel::where('id', $instance->id)
    ->update(['name' => $instance->name]);

// Manually trigger event.
event('eloquent.updating: App\ResearchModel', $instance);
```

The premise of this method is that you already have the required data. If the data required for the event must be read from the DB, then this method is useless.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to "select" first. Then you can update directly. This will run only one query.

```
$research = ResearchModel::where('id',2)->update([
    'name' => 'test',
]);
```

Comment: Will this option trigger model events? also, will this run a query first, or just update?

Comment: @fatnjazzy , this wont trigger event since this is using direct mysql query instead of eloquent. If you want to use eloquent, you MUST find/select first. You might want to trigger the event manually.

Answer (score 0):

Find by id

```php
$research = ResearchModel::find(2);
```

Then you can run update function

```php
$research->update([ 'name' => "test"]);
```

and if u don't want to use

```php
ResearchModel::find(2);
```

then u have to use route binding

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#implicit-binding

Comment: Thanks, but my use-case is not related to routing, this update is not triggered by the client.

Comment: @fatnjazzy then what you want to update .? hole table or specific row.? if specific then u will need id right.?